# Image is being displayed as white box in Django template

Tags: django

The images are showing up as blank boxes. I'm confused as to why this is the case.

**Models.py**

```
class Aircraft(AirlineModelBase):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="uploads/airline", blank=True, null=True)
```

**Settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [ map_path('static'),]
```

**Template**

```
<div class="box"><img src="{{ aircraft.image }}" alt="{{ image.title }}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<div class="box"><img src="{{ aircraft.image.url }}" alt="{{ image.title }}"/>
```

You are referencing the image object instead of the actual url of the image.

Also the `{{ image.title }}` will not be rendered since there is no such `title` field in your model. Maybe you mean this `{{ aircraft.title }}`

Comment: Then you should provide more info about your static files configuration and edit your question with `{{ aircraft.image.url }}`.

Comment: Aviation -> Uploads ->Aircraft/Airline is where they're being stored. When I inspect it using the inspect element, it's picking up the directory, but not grabbing the pictures?